# Can every group $G$ be regarded as an $R$-module for some ring $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

Modules (over rings) generalize vector spaces (over fields).

Let $G$ be a group, let $\textbf{Z}$ be the integers. If $G$ is abelian, then $G$ can be regarded as a $\textbf{Z}$-module. (Side question: does this take $\textbf{Z}$ as a ring or $\textbf{Z}$ as a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-module)?)

Can every group $G$ be regarded as an $R$-module for some ring $R$ (maybe not commutative)? Or does this work only for abelian groups?

Comment: By definition all modules are commutative: this means that if $G$ is not commutative, then $G$ is not a module.

Comment: Actually you can even show that the other module axioms imply commutativity.

Comment: Side answer: It takes $\Bbb Z$ as a ring. Rings have modules, groups do not.

Comment: (By "$\textbf{Z}$ as a group" I meant a [$G$-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-module), which is an abelian group $M$ with an action of $G$ satisfying $g*(a+b) = g*a + g*b$ for $g \in G$ and $a,b \in M$.) This answers all of my questions. Thank you!